# OpenLayers 4.x style polygon depend on amount of features on it..?

Tags: openlayers, styling

I am new in OpenLayers, and I need to make a map, that shows if in some area there are many clients or not..

I have vector layer with polygons (regions.geojson) and vector layer with feature points (clients.geojson).
I would like to change style of the polygon, if there are less than 50 points (clients) on this polygon -> yellow, if between 50-100 orange... ect...

is that possible? hwo t do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, you can do it in two steps.

Step 1) Calculate the number of points in each polygon

One option using only OpenLayers,

```
// get the features
const polys = polysSource.getFeatures();
const points = pointsSource.getFeatures();
// for each polygon
for (let i = 0; i < polys.length; i++) {
    let count = 0;
    // for each point
    for (let j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
        // check if the point intersects the polygon
        // be careful 'intersectsCoordinate' return false if it is on the boundary
        if (polys[i].getGeometry().intersectsCoordinate(points[j].getGeometry().getCoordinates())) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    // get the color
    let color = null;
    if (count < 50) {
        color = 'yellow';
    } else if (count < 100) {
        color = 'orange';
    } else {
        color = 'green';
    }
    // set the color
    polys[i].set('color', color);
}
```

Comments:
I your data is static (I mean it does not change or you don't use any user input), I think is better to prepare the layer on a Desktop GIS like QGIS. Or if your data is on a database like PostGIS, I think is better to build a query.
Using only OpenLayers you could have some limitations like the one I mention about the intersectsCoordinate function (http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Geometry-Geometry.html#intersectsCoordinate). If you need to do more complex spatial analysis you may need some help of an extra library for example turf.js (http://turfjs.org).

Step 2) Style the layer

```
// the polygon style
const getStyle = function (f, r) {
  const c = f.get('color') || 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
  return new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
          width: 1
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: c
      })
  });
};
// the layer style
const layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  visible: false,
  opacity: 0.5,
  source: polysSource,
  style: getStyle
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: As a Clients layer I use dynamicly generated geojson source,

var objectsGeoJSON = document.getElementById('geoVectorValue').value;

 var Clients= new ol.layer.Vector(
  {
   title: 'Client',
   source: new ol.source.Vector()});

var geojsonLayer = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
 Clients.getSource().addFeatures(geojsonLayer.readFeatures(objectsGeoJSON GeoJSON, {
  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
  projection: 'EPSG:4326'
 }));

and I get error: ".getFeatures is not a function"

Comment: Ok I understand why you need to do it on client side. I don't see the invocation,  `Clients.getSource().getFeatures()` is giving you the error?. Remember that `getFeatures` works on the source not the layer.

Comment: yes. I tried to make sth. like this:
const points = Clients.getSource().getFeatures(); and all errors disappeared, but now it looks like the style is still the same. I was trying to change "let color = null;' for some other color to see if it works, but, it is not :( style for every polygon is the same. I will keep on trying to make it work. 
thank you very much for the answer :)

Comment: Are you are getting null color for each polygon?, have you check that the intersection is working?, are you finding points in the polygons and correctly updating the color field?.

Comment: I put different color instead of null, and I don't get it on map, I will try to check if intersection works, cuz I dont know if it works with that source I use (geojson object from hidden field)

Comment: Ok, one more thing, if you change the color attributes after it was already render you may need to render again the layer. In that way, just set the style again to do it after you update all features color value  (`Clients.setStyle(getStyle)`).

Comment: inside this loop:
 for (let i = 0; i < polys.length; i++) {
  let count = 0;
  (..)
   if (polys[i].getGeometry().intersectsCoordinate(points[j].getGeometry().getCoordinates())) {
    count++;
   }
  }

  // get the color
  let color = 'rgba(4,206,24, 1)';
  if (count < 11) {
(..)
  // set the color
  polys[i].set('color', color);
 }
it is impossible to check if intersection works, I was trying to get value of count or TRUE when intersect to the hiddenField but it doesnt return any value. Even alert("alert"); is not working inside this loop... :(

Comment: Let change the function, try this one `polys[i].getGeometry().intersectsExtent(points[j].getGeometry().getExtent())` it will work because it is a point (http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon-Polygon.html#intersectsExtent)

Comment: I found where is problem, it doesn`t count numbers of polys - there is always 0. I will check and try to repair it